# No input in U-Boot command line

Tags: x86, serial-port, device-driver, u-boot

It looks either I get lost the skills how to google for an answer, or missed too obvious option in the configuration. Anyway, I have a U-Boot latest release for x86, which works till command prompt, where unfortunately I can’t type anything.

Added debug prints to *getc()* of ns16550 driver show that the input is actually there, though no echo on the screen and no actual execution of the command if I type it correctly and press Enter.

```
fdtdec_get_config_string: bootcmd
fdtdec_get_config_int: bootsecure
fdtdec_get_int: bootsecure: (not found)
=> getc() d
getc() d
getc() 70
getc() 72
getc() 69
getc() 6e
getc() 74
getc() 65
getc() 6e
getc() 76
getc() d
```

(It has <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and `printenv` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

There’s serial interface only, so I can’t switch to alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared in a broken *hardware* (it's actually a simulation), where unaligned I/O byte access doesn't work. So, what happen is in between of the following code:

```
if (!(serial_in(&com_port->lsr) & UART_LSR_DR))
    return -EAGAIN;
```

Since LSR has address 0x3fd (offset 5), `serial_in()` returns `0xFF` and thus skips return from here assuming data available, while reading RBR returns `0x00` repeatedly.

Solution is either to fix hardware, or make a custom serial driver for it.

Answer (score 1):

U-Boot uses neither Xon/Xoff nor a hardware handshake. Please, check that these are disabled in your terminal emulator.

These three environment variables influence which console is used:

- stderr=serial
- stdin=serial
- stdout=serial

Please, check their value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though it doesn’t help in this case. Yes, the std* devices are correct. No SW flow control in use, please read carefully part where I put debug prints **in** U-Boot. Perhaps I will add the example of debug output to the question later, when I have an access to my lab environment.

Comment: In case of your curiousity I found the real issue, I pushed the answer myself. Anyway, thanks for your try.